# Custom UITextView with bottom border

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm trying to create a custom UITextView class to add bottom border. With following code it doesn't show bottom border. I've alternative solution by adding a view in storyboard and manipulating it as required but that's not best option as I've to use UITextView at many places hence I wanted custom UITextView class. I've similar code for custom UITextField which works.

I also need to change the colour of this border from code.

Any help?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomTextView: UITextView {

    var bottomBorder = UIView()

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: nil)
        self.initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.initialize()

        // Setup Bottom-Border
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        bottomBorder = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        bottomBorder.backgroundColor = .red
        bottomBorder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(bottomBorder)

        bottomBorder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBorder.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBorder.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomBorder.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true // Set Border-Strength
    }

    func initialize() {
    }

}
```

Comment: I use bottom border many times. So most of the time i just simple take one `UIImage view` ant just set the black order image into `UIImageView` and just set the height to the 2px. This is not the proper method I know. but this is the easiest method also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `bottomBorder` in it's `superview`.

so replace following line with new one.

`addSubview(bottomBorder)`

to

`self.superview!.addSubview(bottomBorder)`

you will get red borderline in your textview.

Answer (score 0):

Since all you're doing is adding a bottom border, you could add it straight to the UITextView if you wanted. You would do this as an InspectableVar so you can set it per textview in the storyboard's attribute tab.

```
private var borders = [UITextView: Bool]()

extension UITextView {

  @IBInspectable var showBottomBorder: Bool {
    get {
      guard let b = borders[self] else {
        return true
      }
      return b
    }
    set {
      borders[self] = newValue
      setUpBottomBorder()
    }
  }

  func setUpBottomBorder(){
    let border = UIView()

    border.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    border.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.addSubview(border)

    border.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
    border.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    border.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    border.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
  }
}
```

Comment: I also need to change the colour of this bottom border. How do I do that in code?

Comment: In the setupBottomBorder function it's setting the colour to red. You can change this to whatever you want, or if you need it to be dynamic you can create another IBInspectable var, just copy "showBottomBorder" and instead of Bool it would return a UIColor.